# jQuery: If class exists hide content

Tags: jquery

I have two divs as follow:

```
<div class="after_content"></div>
<div class="inner"><h2>OTHER SIMILAR PACKAGES:</h2></div>
```

I am using the following jquery script to hide the "after_content" div if the "inner" div exists and matches the h2, but it seems that I am doing something wrong, since it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($(".inner").filter(':contains("OTHER SIMILAR PACKAGES:")').exists()){
$(".after_content").hide();
}
});
```

I appreciate your help telling me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `.exists()` method. You have to check that length of the resulting jQuery object is nonzero:

```
if ($(".inner").filter(':contains("OTHER SIMILAR PACKAGES:")').length > 0) {
```

Comment: You don't need the `> 0`, as anything greater than zero is interpreted as true.

Comment: @kalley: You don't need it, but there's nothing wrong with being explicit.

Comment: and to make it the other way, by that I mean if it doesn't exist remove the div, would it be `.lenght = 0` ?

Comment: You'd need `==` (or to be strict `===`) or just `!$(".inner").filter(':contains("OTHER SIMILAR PACKAGES:")').length`

Answer (score 0):

try this
HTML :

```
<div class="after_content">HIDE THESE CONENTS</div>
<div class="inner"><h2>OTHER SIMILAR PACKAGES:</h2></div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".inner").children('h2').html()=="OTHER SIMILAR PACKAGES:"){
        $(".after_content").hide();
    }
})
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/GKSbm/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
           var h2_val = $(".inner h2").text();

           if(h2_val == 'OTHER SIMILAR PACKAGES:')
           {
               $(".after_content").hide();
           }
     });
```